# Polymer binding array and computed properties/bindings

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer-1.0

I try simple example: `array binding`, `computed property` and `computed binding`

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
    <template>
        <p>list of r: 
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{r}}">
                <span>{{item}}</span>,
            </template>
        <p>
        <p>computed property: {{length}}<p>
        <p>computed value: {{_length(r)}}<p>
        <button on-click='_add'>Add r</button>
    </template>
</dom-module>

Polymer({
    is: "my-element",
    properties: {
        r: {
            type:Object,
            value:[1,2]
        },
        length: {
            type: Number,
            computed: '_length(r)'
        }
    },
    _length: function(r) {
        return r.length
    },
    _add: function() {
        this.push('r', this.r.length+1);
        <!-- this.notifyPath('r', this.r); -->
    }

});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rudux/4Lfc3fjy/)

and can't understand, why `repeated template` refresh on `push` new value, but `computed propety` and `computed binding` are not refresh

Comment: IMO, the reason the computed property and value are not updated is because 'r' is not changed - it is an array, its properties have changed (like 'length'), but the reference that 'r' holds isn't. This https://jsfiddle.net/4Lfc3fjy/1/ would work because, now the computed property and value depend on 'r.length' which is changed due to 'this.push'

Comment: How abount [`notifyPath`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#set-path)? If i notify `r` changed, why computed values are not refreshed?

Comment: As far as I can see from the polymer [source](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/master/src/standard/notify-path.html#L98), `notifyPath` checks if oldValue and newValue are different,  but they are the same, hence it doesn't notify for any binding

Comment: You are right. Polymer `push` method notifies about `r.length` changes ([source](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/master/src/standard/notify-path.html#L444)) but not `r` , because `r` not changed. Thanks.

Comment: Not 100% sure about this, but I think I've done it before. Try changing `computed: '_length(r)'` to `computed: '_length(r.splices)'`. Also `type` should be `Array` should it now?

Comment: @user2422321. Yes. I saw this in source, and when reread documentation. Binding to `r.length` and `r.splices` works.